# Webkit Keyframes not working

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I want to use keyframes to make a client's site logo (just text using @font-face) fade in and out of different colors. Somehow, I can't get this to work at all!

```
@-webkit-keyframes colorPulse { 0% {color: rgba(236, 250, 42, 0.6);} 
50% {color: rgba(253, 149, 223, 0.6);} 100% {color: rgba(1, 218, 213, 0.6);} }

#site-logo {
font-family: KaBlamo;
font-size: 90px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
margin: 20px 0 .4em;
-webkit-animation: colorPulse 15s infinite alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works pretty good:

https://jsfiddle.net/3frdpw4h/

Which browser are you using? Maybe you have to supply the unprefixed animation property + keyframes rule?

```
@-webkit-keyframes colorPulse {
    0% {color: rgba(236, 250, 42, 0.6);}
    50% {color: rgba(253, 149, 223, 0.6);}
    100% {color: rgba(1, 218, 213, 0.6);}
}
@keyframes colorPulse {
    0% {color: rgba(236, 250, 42, 0.6);}
    50% {color: rgba(253, 149, 223, 0.6);}
    100% {color: rgba(1, 218, 213, 0.6);}
}

#site-logo {
    font-family: KaBlamo;
    font-size: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    margin: 20px 0 .4em;
    -webkit-animation: colorPulse 15s infinite alternate;
    animation: colorPulse 15s infinite alternate;
}
```